# Javascript Nodejs Value not pushing into array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

```
module.exports.findUser = function(query){
  var result = []; 
  User.find(query, function(err, data){
    result.push(data);
  });
  return result;
}
```

I try to push the data array into result, but keep getting an empty array back.

Comment: `find` looks like it is async, so you are returning before it is finished

Answer (score 3):

`User.find()` is async, so you can't just return the value immediately. You have two options to solve this problem:

Option 1:

Accept a callback parameter and call it when results are ready:

```
module.exports.findUser = function(query, cb) {
    var result = []; 
    User.find(query, function(err, data){
        result.push(data);
        cb(err, result);
    });
}
```

Common Node.js convention is to have callbacks that have the first parameter `err`, which would return any errors, and the second parameter the actual data you're giving back.

This would then be used like:

```
findUser('query', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Option 2:

Return a `Promise` which can then be chained. This isn't super common Node.js convention (Option 1 is), but it's becoming a more prevalent and will likely become the norm in a year or two:

```
module.exports.findUser = function(query) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var result = []; 
        User.find(query, function(err, data){
            err && reject(err) || result.push(data) && resolve(result);
        });
    }
}
```

This would be used like this:

```
findUser('query').then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => throw new Error(err));
```

Comment: it's just return me [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]

Comment: That's correct, it should return a promise.. your nearly there..  Basically you need to attach a `then`.. eg.  `findUser('xyz').then(function (data) {`

Comment: `This isn't super common Node.js convention`  Finger crossed this will change, I've heard that Node developers are even on about making built-in's Promise based..  That with the `async` & `await` will be great..

Comment: @Keith I've noticed them trending more and more with Promises too, which makes me happy. I'm a big fan of promises. An interesting thing is you can actually do BOTH as well, accept a callback and return a Promise. They aren't mutually exclusive.